# Creating the Babylon.js declaration file from Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, babylonjs

BabylonJS provides a gulp task to create their definition file, but right now it's resulting in an error reported here:

https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/issues/221

"Command is too long"

Does anyone know what this error means? And if so, is there a way to fix it? Or failing that, is there a working declaration file out there somewhere?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about BabylonJS's build process, not programming

Comment: It's about TypeScript compiler errors. Where would be a better place to ask?

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh: I disagree. Build produces code, which is a result of programming. Question is concrete and asking about a specific issue. A possible answer would provide all possible causes of this error. If there are too many of those - then only most common ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this, should it affect anyone else.

The path name is too long in most user's folder structure, eg. `C:/users/me/documents/work/babylon`

I cloned the repo into `C:/b/` and ran the build tool:

`gulp typescript`

This successfully created the babylon.d.ts file in the Gulp folder.